# Can you make a GET request that will trigger embedded javascript/php in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request

I'm new to node.js and I've been looking for my answer to this question for quite a while now.
I've already got my GET request and have tested it to verify it works.

My question is,
I have an image that updates on visit. I'm trying to make a get request that will also trigger that image.

It does work when I feed the raw image URL. I want it so that if I had say 5 on 1 html page I could just link the html page and it would update the images according.

//note: the image is a php image (updates on request for it)

Comment: What code you tried ?

Comment: not sure what you mean but my request is:
    requestify.get(url).then(function(response) {
    response.getBody();
    response.body;
    });